# is there a limit to how many USB devices / connections you can have on a Mac?

Tags: usb

I have a LOT of usb devices mostly drives, but they are mostly powered and have their own brick... I have two USB3 hubs that are powered and are the highest rated I could find online (made by Anker) and yet there comes a point where I connect another drive and all the drives disconnect at once... how can I get around this?

Comment: The maximum number of devices that can be connected to a computers USB port is 127 according to the USB specifications.

Comment: Launch to System Info tool (click on Apple icon in menu bar, hold down Alt) and take a look at the USB info just when you have the maximum amount of devices connected before it stops working. Also, please provide numbers. What is “a lot”? 10? 50? 100?

Comment: Definitely not 127... I think I have about 9-10 drives plus various USB peripherals, everything fed by two Anker USB hubs with big power bricks... I count 28 lines in the USB section of System Info...

Answer (score 1):

The limit is 127. That’s not a Mac limit, it’s the USB spec. If you’re having problems with fewer than 127 devices (internal devices and buses count against the limit), it’s more likely to be a power problem.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but in case anyone else is looking.  My understanding is that USB has an "assignment" limit of 127.  IE there are only 127 address slots.  Many devices take up multiple addresses, and like the OP here discovered, you can run into the issue much quicker than you think, if you've got "127" in your head.

This isn't user-configurable, etc.  It's at the processor / motherboard level and has to do with the number of USB Host controllers, etc.

For me it's MIDI USB devices that are causing me grief.  Hope that helps.